# Nested Resource-Management in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, localization, resources

Sorry if this is already explained somewhere, but I did not find an existing solution. Perhaps I just don't now for which keywords I should look.

My question is: **Is it possible to have a nested ResourceManagement.**

Lets say I define the following resx files:

```
Resources.resx
Resources.es.resx
Resources.dark.resx
Resources.dark.es.resx
```

I want the following behaviour:

- If no CultureInfo is defined the Resources.resx should be taken.
- If the CultureInfo "dark" is set the Resources.dark.resx should be taken.
- If language "es" is selected, the corresponding Resource file shoul be taken.
- If a resource is not defined, the ResourceManager should fall back to the less specific Resource file.

How could I achieve this behaviour?